# Just once in launcher option in android

Tags: android, android-launcher

I trying to detect if the my app is default launcher. When the launcher app is promted with Always And Just once.

Whenever I click "JUST ONCE" my app thinks it is default? Why is this happening?

I am using the following to check the default part:

```
private boolean isMyLauncherDefault() 
{
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

    List<IntentFilter> filters = new ArrayList<IntentFilter>();
    filters.add(filter);

    final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
    List<ComponentName> activities = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
    final PackageManager packageManager = (PackageManager) getPackageManager();

    // You can use name of your package here as third argument
    packageManager.getPreferredActivities(filters, activities, null);

    for (ComponentName activity : activities) 
    {
        if (myPackageName.equals(activity.getPackageName())) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
private boolean isMyLauncherDefault() 
{
    boolean returnValue = false;
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    final ResolveInfo mInfo = pm.resolveActivity(intent, 0);
    if (mInfo != null) {
         if(myAppname.equals
                     (pm.getApplicationLabel(mInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo))
               returnValue = true;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Edit:

[getPreferredActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPreferredActivities%28java.util.List%3Candroid.content.IntentFilter%3E,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.content.ComponentName%3E,%20java.lang.String%29):Returns the total number of registered preferred activities. 
Retrieve all preferred activities, previously added with addPreferredActivity(IntentFilter, int, ComponentName[], ComponentName), that are currently registered with the system.
I think this will return all the activities name which are registered for that particular intent.

[resolveActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29):Returns a ResolveInfo containing the final activity intent that was determined to be the best action. Returns null if no matching activity was found. So in this case we have restricted resolve activity to match DEFAULT app by specifying `CATEGORY_DEFAULT`.

Check this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/UkfP70MtjGA) answered by Hackborn that we should use `resolveActivity()` to find default app.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. I was not in town for a couple days. I tried your code. It is not working.. What is myAppname?

Comment: myAppname is application name.

Comment: How to get the application name?

Comment: If application name is defined in strings.xml then you can use String appName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

Comment: Great. It worked. What is the difference between your code and mine?

Comment: filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT); I think if you add this in your code then this will also find out only default app for that particular intent.